# Android EditText changing position when I change the textSize programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm have an editText with a big font and my idea was to reduce the size when it approaches the screen border, so i'm changing to text size programmatically but the result is that the text also changes position in my view. How can I prevent this?

Here is the text centered
[image: Layout]

After changing the size
[image: moved]

The layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_user_container"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/reason_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:digits="0123456789.,"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="72sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        tools:text="0" />
</LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here Im changing the size:

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
            if (mAmountText.getText().length() > 7) {
                mAmountText.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.small));
            } else {
                mAmountText.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.big));
            }
        }
```